# JS 'onload' function calls infine time

Tags: javascript

If we replace `onclick` event with `onload`, then why bulb is keeping on and off infinite time ? Here is example [from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb), just replace onclick with onload and submit code.

Example:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function changeImage() {
    element = document.getElementById('myimage')
    if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
        element.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        element.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>

<img id="myimage" onload="changeImage()"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because every time the changeImage function runs, it swaps the image `src` which in turn, fires a new `onLoad` event, thus running the function again!

Comment: I think onload is called when whole page is loaded, but within js function how page is getting refresh again and again ?

Comment: When it is loading on first time its color is changing and again it is get loaded because it is loading a new image so it is loading each time so the things are going to infinity

Comment: _"I think onload is called when whole page is loaded"_ - An onload handler attached to the page is called when the whole page is loaded, but your onload handler is attached to the img element so it's called when that img element loads an image... Why would you want to replace the onclick with onload in the first place? What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onload` event of an image fires every time an image is successfully loaded. This means if you change the `src`, then a new image will be loaded into the `<img>` "container" and will trigger an `onload` (or `onerror`) when it is done.

You must remove the event handler. `this.onload = null;` will do it. (Assuming you are inside your even handler - in this case, you'd need to do `onLoad="changeImage(); this.onload = null;"`, or adjust your code in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly,

on "page" load :

```
<body onload="...">
```

on "image" load :

```
<img onload="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

because it's infinetely loading new image

just add

```
element.onload = undefined;
```

to your function